# Java: Find out if a number is prime recursively

Tags: java, recursion, primes

I'm writing a function that returns true if a number is prime, and false otherwise

Here is my current code:

```
    public static boolean checkPrime(int n, int currDivisor){
        if(n < 2){
            return true;
        }
        if(currDivisor == (n/2)){
            return true;
        }
        else if(n % currDivisor == 0 ){
            return false;           
        }
        else{
            return checkPrime(n, currDivisor + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(checkPrime(23352, 2));
    }
```

It works for a lot of test cases except numbers like "1000000007" where I get an Out of memory error. How could I tweak this code to be more efficient space-wise?

Comment: well for starters, don't use a recursive function

Comment: The fundamental problem is that recursion is not the right approach.  Primality testing is not a recursive problem, and you will always exceed available storage quite quickly for large numbers.  I suggest you do some research on the web on the topic of "primality testing".

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb that you guys follow when deciding whether or not to use a recursive function or not? For some reason I was fairly certain this was a recursive problem.

Comment: recursion uses an enormous amount of heap space.. the call stack gets very large because of the amount of information it needs to keep track of each iteration. i would just standard loops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that your program is it's buggy.  It seems to think that 0, 1, & 4 are primes and that 3 isn't.  The second problem I see is that it's wasting stack frames not properly dealing with simple cases before recursing.  Here's my rework of your code:

```
public static boolean checkPrime(int n) {
    return checkPrime1(n, 3);
}

public static boolean checkPrime1(int n, int currDivisor) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return false;
    }

    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return (n == 2);
    }

    if (currDivisor * currDivisor > n) {
        return true;
    }

    if (n % currDivisor == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return checkPrime1(n, currDivisor + 2);
}
```

As far as handling:

```
System.out.println(checkPrime(1000000007));
```

You'll still get an `java.lang.StackOverflowError` but that's not the end of the story.  Most languages make decisions of how much memory to allocate to specific purposes.  It's the rare language like Perl that will reallocate memory to whatever resource is demanding it most and not make assumptions about how a program should behave.

You can change the amount of memory allocated to Java's stack -- calling `java` with the `-Xss2m` argument allocates sufficient extra stack to let you test 1000000007 (`true`, by the way.)

If you change the three `int` declarations above to `long`, you'll be able to test numbers like `2547487897L` or larger as long as you expand the stack (`-Xss4m` in this case.)

I'm not saying that this is a good problem for recursion, it isn't.  But if you're going to use recursion, use it wisely.  It's poor recursion that's gives recursion a bad name.  There are inefficient recursive Fibonnaci algorithms (usually doubly recursive) and efficient (singly recursive) ones.  Recursive code usually works best with recursive data.

Some languages, not yet Java consistently, can optimize the above code as a tail recursion and make it effectively iterative performance.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental problem is that recursion is not the right approach. Primality testing is not a recursive problem, and you will always exceed available storage quite quickly for large numbers. I suggest you do some research on the web on the topic of "primality testing".

As to a rule of thumb for deciding if a problem is recursive, I've been doing this so long I'm not sure I can express what has become completely intuitive, so I'll let someone else do it.

However, it's worth pointing out that some problems that are mathematically recursive have computational solutions where iteration is far, far better than naive recursion. The prime (hah!) example of that is Fibonacci numbers. For large n the naively recursive solution eats memory and performs redundant calculations, while the iterative solution is faster and better all around.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that recursion is rarely the best solution to a problem? There is almost always a better way to do it in a loop?

Comment: Not at all! Some problems are recursive by nature, such as searching a binary tree.  Recursion tends to get overused, but there is an entire set of problems where recursion is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*by mostafa asem aljbali*/
    static boolean isPrime(int num, int i){

        if (num <= 2){
            return (num == 2) ? true : false;
        }
        if (num % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
        if (i * i > num){
            return true;
        }

        return isPrime(num , (i + 1));
    }
 public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Is Prime: "+ isPrime(7, 2));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).